# Net Core 2.2 to Net Core 3.1 migration error

Tags: c#, migration, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to migrate from Net Core 2.2 to Net Core 3.1

After solving a lot of problems, got this one and was unable to find solution until now.

The project works running on VS 2019 (IIS Express) but fails at server using real IIS (hosted at AWS).

The exception is:

> Error DatabaseTarget(Name=allDb_wrapped): Error when writing to database. Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.LoadServerProperties(MySqlConnection connection)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.OpenConnection(String connectionString, LogEventInfo logEventInfo)
>   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.EnsureConnectionOpen(String connectionString, LogEventInfo logEventInfo)
>   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteLogEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo logEvent, String connectionString)

and

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content)
>   at ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify the IIS settings Once. 
In case of  uses 32-bit mode, make sure to enable the App Pool to be able to use 32-bit instruction. Check Framework version map it correctly, 
Enable 32-Application should be “True”. 
After that do iisreset once.

Comment: Enable 32-Bit Applications was set to False.

After changing to True and performing an IIsreset, the error is the same!

Comment: TRY stop the ManageEngine .NET Agent service
     - Open command prompt using "Run as Administrator" option
     - Type regsvr32 "path of the profiler"   (Profiler dll path is... Agent Installation PathDotNetAgentClrProfilerAgent.dll) 

then rest IIS - iireset
then start Start the ManageEngine .NET Agent service

Comment: Hi, cannot find ManageEngine .NET Agent service!